# Allow only 1 linebreak in a string javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to only limit line breaks to 1 at a time.

```
var foo = "hello\n\n\nworld\n\nfoobar"
```

desired result:

```
 var foo = "hello\nworld\nfoobar"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` to remove excess of `\n` from the string.

`\n+` will match all the `\n` which are repeated one or more times.
`g` flag is used to remove all occurrences of `\n` from the string.

```js
var foo = "hello\n\n\nworld\n\nfoobar";
foo = foo.replace(/\n+/g, '\n');

console.log(foo);
alert(foo);
```

Comment: @teddybear123 If this answer has helped you, kindly consider accepting the answer. If not, add the comments here